# Injecting variables into a quoted expression

Tags: macros, metaprogramming, elixir, hygiene

I have a quoted expression such as this one:

```
ast = quote do
  IO.puts x
end
```

And I wish to inject a variable into the expression so that x has a value, and the expression won't raise a `CompileError` due to  `x` being undefined when evaluated like so:

```
Code.eval_quoted ast, [x: "Hello, world!"]
```

This AST is passed to me, and I cannot change the code it is generated with. I can modify the AST after I've been passed it though.

I thought to do this I could transform the AST to resemble this quoted expression:

```
ast = quote do
  x = var!(x)
  IO.puts x
end
```

After attempting this my AST looks like so:

```
{:__block__, [],
[{:=, [],
  [{:x, [], Elixir}, {:var!, [context: Check.Runner], [{:x, [], Elixir}]}]},
  {{:., [], [{:__aliases__, [alias: false], [:IO]}, :puts]}, [],
  [{:x, [], Check.RunnerTest}]}]}
```

This doesn't work. I thought that this might be due to having an incorrect value for the context of `var!`.

Resolution: I now realise that the variables were in the incorrect scope, and I need an AST like this:

```
{:__block__, [],
[{:=, [],
  [{:x, [], Check.RunnerTest},
    {:var!, [context: Check.Runner], [{:x, [], Check.Runner}]}]},
  {{:., [], [{:__aliases__, [alias: false], [:IO]}, :puts]}, [],
  [{:x, [], Check.RunnerTest}]}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should just work. In fact, you have written:

```
ast = quote do
  x = var!(x)
  IO.puts x
end
```

But you showed the AST for some other code, one where you assigned `1` to `var!(x)`. In other words, there is nothing wrong with the code above.

Comment: Ah, I pasted in the incorrect one. After reading your comment below I realise I had the variable in the incorrect scope due to setting the incorrect context. I have updated the question above.

Comment: Now that you updated the question, the question itself is wrong (the example does work) and this answer is somewhat wrong. :P

Comment: Yup. It's all a bit of a mess. Probably best to walk away now!